# Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given

Tags: php, html, css

Hola soy nuevo en esto de *PHP* y estoy enredado con un formulario que me da este error en el navegador:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in D:\xammp\htdocs\formularios\CRUD\update.php on line 115

Cuando le doy enviar me sale ese error ya he intentado correr `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` y me deja de dar error pero cuando envió el formulario no me redirige ni envía los datos a la base de datos.

Dejo el código aquí:

```html
<?php

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$nombre = $email = $investigador = $fecha = $clase = $tipo = $ciudadcaso = $condicionjuridica = $cliente = "";
$nombre_err = $email_err = $investigador_err =$fecha_err = $clase_err = $tipo_err = $ciudadcaso_err = $condicionjuridica_err = $cliente_err  = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
 // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    
    // Validate name
    $input_nombre = trim($_POST["nombre"]);
    if(empty($input_nombre)){
        $nombre_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_nombre, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $nombre_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre válido.";
    } else{
        $nombre = $input_nombre;
    }
    
    // Validate address email
    $input_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    if(empty($input_email)){
        $email_err = "Por favor ingrese un email.";     
    } else{
        $email = $input_email;
    }
    
    // Validate investigador
    $input_investigador = trim($_POST["investigador"]);
    if(empty($input_investigador)){
        $investigador_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_investigador, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $investigador_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre válido.";
    } else{
        $investigador = $input_investigador;
    }
    // Validate address fecha
    $input_fecha = trim($_POST["fecha"]);
    if(empty($input_fecha)){
        $fecha_err = "Por favor ingrese una fecha valida.";     
    } else{
        $fecha = $input_fecha;
    }
    // Validate address clase
    $input_clase = trim($_POST["clase"]);
    if(empty($input_clase)){
        $clase_err = "Por favor ingrese una clase valida.";     
    } else{
        $clase = $input_clase;
    }
    // Validate address tipo
    $input_tipo = trim($_POST["tipo"]);
    if(empty($input_tipo)){
        $tipo_err = "Por favor ingrese una fecha valida.";     
    } else{
        $tipo = $input_tipo;
    }
    // Validate address ciudadcaso
    $input_ciudadcaso = trim($_POST["ciudadcaso"]);
    if(empty($input_ciudadcaso)){
        $ciudadcaso_err = "Por favor ingrese una ciudad valida.";     
    } else{
        $ciudadcaso = $input_ciudadcaso;
    }
    // Validate address condicionjuridica
    $input_condicionjuridica = trim($_POST["condicionjuridica"]);
    if(empty($input_condicionjuridica)){
        $condicionjuridica_err = "Por favor ingrese una condicionjuridica valida.";     
    } else{
        $condicionjuridica = $input_condicionjuridica;
    }
    // Validate address cliente
    $input_cliente = trim($_POST["cliente"]);
    if(empty($input_cliente)){
        $cliente_err = "Por favor ingrese un cliente valido.";     
    } else{
        $cliente = $input_cliente;
    }
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($nombre_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($investigador_err) && empty($fecha_err) && empty($clase_err) && empty($tipo_err) && empty($ciudadcaso_err) && empty($condicionjuridica_err) && empty($cliente_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE datos SET nombre=?, email=?, investigador=?, fecha=?, clase=?, tipo=?, ciudadcaso=?, condicionjuridica=?, cliente=?, WHERE id=?";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $param_nombre, $param_email, $param_investigador, $param_fecha, $param_clase, $param_tipo, $param_ciudadcaso, $param_condicionjuridica, $param_cliente, $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_nombre = $nombre;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_investigador = $investigador;
            $param_fecha = $fecha;
            $param_clase = $clase;
            $param_tipo = $tipo;
            $param_ciudadcaso = $ciudadcaso;
            $param_condicionjuridica = $condicionjuridica;
            $param_cliente = $cliente;
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
         
        }
            // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }  
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $nombre = $row["nombre"];
                    $email = $row["email"];
                    $investigador = $row["investigador"];
                    $fecha = $row["fecha"];
                    $clase = $row["clase"];
                    $tipo = $row["tipo"];
                    $ciudadcaso = $row["ciudadcaso"];
                    $condicionjuridica = $row["condicionjuridica"];
                    $cliente = $row["cliente"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
           
        }
         // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        
        
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    
    }else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Actualizar Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Actualizar Registro</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>Edite los valores de entrada y envíe para actualizar el registro.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($nombre_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $nombre_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>email</label>
                            <textarea name="email" class="form-control"><?php echo $email; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($investigador_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>investigador</label>
                            <input type="text" name="investigador" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $investigador; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $investigador_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($fecha_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>fecha</label>
                            <textarea name="fecha" class="form-control"><?php echo $fecha; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $fecha_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($clase_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>clase</label>
                            <textarea name="clase" class="form-control"><?php echo $clase; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $clase_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($tipo_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>tipo</label>
                            <textarea name="tipo" class="form-control"><?php echo $tipo; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $tipo_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($ciudadcaso_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>ciudadcaso</label>
                            <textarea name="ciudadcaso" class="form-control"><?php echo $ciudadcaso; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $ciudadcaso_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($condicionjuridica_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>condicionjuridica</label>
                            <textarea name="condicionjuridica" class="form-control"><?php echo $condicionjuridica; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $condicionjuridica_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($cliente_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>cliente</label>
                            <textarea name="cliente" class="form-control"><?php echo $cliente; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $cliente_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería bastante gracias.

Comment: No viniste tu antes ??? -- En la linea 115 aprox, estas cerrando el $stmt fuera del IF, prueba a meterlo dentro, pero al final. Lo que vive en el IF, muere en el IF

Comment: pero haciendo mas pequeño el formulario me funciona. y cuando lo meto deja de dar error pero no envia a la base de datos. sigo con el mismo problema jajaj

Comment: Ahhh entonces si eres tu XD bueno, entonces te pregunto, por que hay un exit durante el anterior if ??

Comment: para que redirija a la pagina incio una vez se envia el formulario

Comment: Yo supongo que el error de $stmt no tiene nada que ver con que no te llegue nada al servidor. Por que no puedo ver donde le asignas parametros, o si esos parametros se estan asignando a las variables correspondientes.  Por ejemplo, el nombre esta pasando a param_nombre, pero no veo aun donde lo estas cargando.

Comment: ire a hacerme un cursillo de php para mejorar por que ando perdido muchas gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer y es super simple, es ir imprimiendo / mostrando, aquellas variables que estas usando. Si con el stmt dentro no te da error, pero no pasa nada, revisa las variables. Muchas veces imprimo todo a ver si llega a servidor, o en que momento llega a perderse (por que hasta un acento olvide una vez, donde NO DEBIA IR XD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta colocando este codigo, solo hice un par de modificaciones y las deje con comentarios //

```html
    <?php

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$nombre = $email = $investigador = $fecha = $clase = $tipo = $ciudadcaso = $condicionjuridica = $cliente = "";
$nombre_err = $email_err = $investigador_err =$fecha_err = $clase_err = $tipo_err = $ciudadcaso_err = $condicionjuridica_err = $cliente_err  = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
 // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    
    // Validate name
    $input_nombre = trim($_POST["nombre"]);
    if(empty($input_nombre)){
        $nombre_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_nombre, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $nombre_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre válido.";
    } else{
        $nombre = $input_nombre;
    }
    
    // Validate address email
    $input_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    if(empty($input_email)){
        $email_err = "Por favor ingrese un email.";     
    } else{
        $email = $input_email;
    }
    
    // Validate investigador
    $input_investigador = trim($_POST["investigador"]);
    if(empty($input_investigador)){
        $investigador_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_investigador, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $investigador_err = "Por favor ingrese un nombre válido.";
    } else{
        $investigador = $input_investigador;
    }
    // Validate address fecha
    $input_fecha = trim($_POST["fecha"]);
    if(empty($input_fecha)){
        $fecha_err = "Por favor ingrese una fecha valida.";     
    } else{
        $fecha = $input_fecha;
    }
    // Validate address clase
    $input_clase = trim($_POST["clase"]);
    if(empty($input_clase)){
        $clase_err = "Por favor ingrese una clase valida.";     
    } else{
        $clase = $input_clase;
    }
    // Validate address tipo
    $input_tipo = trim($_POST["tipo"]);
    if(empty($input_tipo)){
        $tipo_err = "Por favor ingrese una fecha valida.";     
    } else{
        $tipo = $input_tipo;
    }
    // Validate address ciudadcaso
    $input_ciudadcaso = trim($_POST["ciudadcaso"]);
    if(empty($input_ciudadcaso)){
        $ciudadcaso_err = "Por favor ingrese una ciudad valida.";     
    } else{
        $ciudadcaso = $input_ciudadcaso;
    }
    // Validate address condicionjuridica
    $input_condicionjuridica = trim($_POST["condicionjuridica"]);
    if(empty($input_condicionjuridica)){
        $condicionjuridica_err = "Por favor ingrese una condicionjuridica valida.";     
    } else{
        $condicionjuridica = $input_condicionjuridica;
    }
    // Validate address cliente
    $input_cliente = trim($_POST["cliente"]);
    if(empty($input_cliente)){
        $cliente_err = "Por favor ingrese un cliente valido.";     
    } else{
        $cliente = $input_cliente;
    }
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($nombre_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($investigador_err) && empty($fecha_err) && empty($clase_err) && empty($tipo_err) && empty($ciudadcaso_err) && empty($condicionjuridica_err) && empty($cliente_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
//el problmea esta en el where, la coma antes del where que colocaste esta demas
         $sql = "UPDATE nombre SET nombre=?, email=?, investigador=?, fecha=?, clase=?, tipo=?, ciudadcaso=?, condicionjuridica=?, cliente=? WHERE id=?";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
//aqui solo queda "sssssssss" y quitas param_id
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssi", $param_nombre, $param_email, $param_investigador, $param_fecha, $param_clase, $param_tipo, $param_ciudadcaso, $param_condicionjuridica, $param_cliente, $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_nombre = $nombre;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_investigador = $investigador;
            $param_fecha = $fecha;
            $param_clase = $clase;
            $param_tipo = $tipo;
            $param_ciudadcaso = $ciudadcaso;
            $param_condicionjuridica = $condicionjuridica;
            $param_cliente = $cliente;
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                //hacemos un mysqli_error($link) para verificar si el error es con mysql
                //esto es solo para pruebas, el usuario no debe saber cuales son los problemas con la BD.  
                echo "Something's wrong with the query: " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
            
        }  
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $nombre = $row["nombre"];
                    $email = $row["email"];
                    $investigador = $row["investigador"];
                    $fecha = $row["fecha"];
                    $clase = $row["clase"];
                    $tipo = $row["tipo"];
                    $ciudadcaso = $row["ciudadcaso"];
                    $condicionjuridica = $row["condicionjuridica"];
                    $cliente = $row["cliente"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            } else{
                //hacemos un mysqli_error($link) para verificar si el error es con mysql  
                //esto es solo para pruebas, el usuario no debe saber cuales son los problemas con la BD.
                echo "Something's wrong with the query: " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
           // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
         
        
        
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    
    }else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: no te acabo de entender muy bien. podrías dar un ejemplo porfa.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda. copie tu codigo y me sigue dando lo mismo cuado envio el formulario la pagina se refresca pero no cambia nada incluso los valores en el formulario siguen y no redirecciona. y cuando no cierro dentro del if me sale el error en la linea 122

Comment: solo ve colocando este codigo en diferentes secciones para saber si es un error de sql o sintaxis mysqli_error($link);

Comment: en el sighiente codigo que es el "sssi" no entiendo a que hace referencia                       if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $param_nombre, $param_email, $param_investigador, $param_fecha, $param_clase, $param_tipo, $param_ciudadcaso, $param_condicionjuridica, $param_cliente, $param_id);

Comment: hace referencia al tipo de variable, y justamente hay tienes un problema que debes solucionar, "i" : la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero, "d" : la variable correspondiente es de tipo double, "s": la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
"b" : la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes, entonces supongamos que todas tus variables son de tipo string y tienes 7 variables, debe ir "sssssss"

Comment: te deje arreglado el codigo, intenta ejecutandolo y avisas

Comment: ya vi tu error, revisa en los comentarios que te deje

Comment: en la setencia SQL antes del where colocaste una coma, quitala, quedaria asi: $sql = "UPDATE nombre SET nombre=?, email=?, investigador=?, fecha=?, clase=?, tipo=?, ciudadcaso=?, condicionjuridica=?, cliente=? WHERE id=?"; y mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssi", $param_nombre, $param_email, $param_investigador, $param_fecha, $param_clase, $param_tipo, $param_ciudadcaso, $param_condicionjuridica, $param_cliente, $param_id);

Comment: ya probe localmente y a mi me funciono